# Mathematica "is not an integer" error

Tags: integer, wolfram-mathematica, dsolve

I'm running some simulations with Mathematica with NDSolve, and I need to introduce the effect of temperature. I define a table of random numbers and then make a function out of it, this way:

```
 randomtablex = 
      Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {i, 1, 
        IntegerPart[3 tspacer/deltats] + 1}];
    randomtabley = 
      Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {i, 1, 
        IntegerPart[3 tspacer/deltats] + 1}];
    randomtablez = 
      Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {i, 1, 
        IntegerPart[3 tspacer/deltats] + 1}];
    Bterp[t_] := 
      {randomtablex[[IntegerPart[t/deltats] + 1]], 
        randomtabley[[IntegerPart[t/deltats] + 1]], 
        randomtablez[[IntegerPart[t/deltats] + 1]]};
```

Where `3tspacer` is the time of integration and `deltats` is the time when the thermal field changes.
The simulation runs fine and the results are correct, but everytime i get this error message:

Part::pspec: "Part specification 1+IntegerPart[1000000000000 t] is neither an integer nor a list of integers."

As i said its not really a problem, but it bugs me that it keeps appearing... Is there any way to know where it came from, or should i just turn it off?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will happen if you access `Bterp[]` with a symbolic argument `t`

Try this:

```
ClearAll[Bterp]
Bterp[t_?NumericQ] := ....
```

http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820

Aside, `IntegerPart[x]+1` is the same as `Ceiling[x]` (assuming x>0...)

Comment: That did work, but now i get another error: 

NDSolve::ndfdmc: Computed derivatives do not have dimensionality consistent with the initial conditions.

NDSolve solves a differential vectorial equation, so my guess is that it has something to do with NDSolve not considering Bterp a vector after the change...

Comment: You need to play that same trick at a higher level - make sure  the function directly supplied to ndsolve is defined so that it only evaluates for numeric values. (very common issue, you'd think NDSolve, NIntegrate, etc wouldn't even try symbolic evaluation, but they do )